# HTTPS is blocking captcha

Tags: php, html

When I go to my Login page, my website cannot load captcha form on that page, because it's using HTTPS. 
What changes I should add to my website to allow the captcha to load on my site when it use HTTPS ?
how to make it to work with HTTPS.
I'm using 3rd party captcha service from google. If I remove SSL, then with HTTP my website can load captcha. Also on other pages, google map cannot load too.

Comment: Are you using a 3rd party captcha API?

Comment: Not enough information. Is the captcha only available over http?

Comment: I have updated my post. I use 3rd party captcha, it is working with http

Comment: Well, I don't know which one you use but I suggest reCAPTCHA. It works on https too: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically https pages won't load http pages, because that could be a security risk. Fortunately, most 3rd party services allow both http *and* https access. Usually it's as simple as replacing the `http` in the code they provide with `https`. Obviously this depends on exactly which tools you are using, and some services from smaller companies aren't available over https at all.